# Detour null function

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, ida, detours

I've been trying to detour a nullsub, this function is used with log purposes, but as the program is compiled under release flags it got removed and I'd like to restore it.

IDA reports as follow:

```
.text:004BAC10 ; void __thiscall nullsub_2(void *)
.text:004BAC10 nullsub_2       proc near       
.text:004BAC10                 retn
.text:004BAC10 nullsub_2       endp
```

My attempt is to detour this address with my own log function, but Microsoft Detours 3.0 throws **ERROR_INVALID_BLOCK**

I think I get this error as it does not have space to place the jump function, and I don't have any idea how I can fix it.

Comment: Asked the same question in Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange website, link here: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12002/detour-null-function